Any explanation why Maria has a human name?
So in Grendizer they gave an explanation why people from planet Earth and humans look alike "they might have the same ancestors" , they speak another language so Daisuke is the adoptive human name of Duke Fleed, and they have samples of words from that other language people from planet Fleed speaks, but Duke Fleed sister Maria has a human/latin name.
Any explanation why Maria has a human name?
